# jQuery get text between brackets

Tags: jquery

I use this jQuery Code to get var values from text inside div

```
$('div').each(function() {
  var a = $(this).html();
  var b = a.split('/');
  $(this).html("<span>" + b[0] + "</span><span>" + b[1] + "</span><span>" + b[2] + "</span>");
  var c = $(this).text();
  var d = $(this).find("span").eq(0).text();
  var e = $(this).find("span").eq(1).text();
  var f = $(this).find("span").eq(2).text();
});
```

So HTML will be in this shape

```
<div>Text1/Text2/Text3</div>
```

I want to change my jQuery code to get text between brackets not "/"

```
<div>[Text1][Text2][Text3]</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you managed to write (or even understand) the code you're using now I'm pretty sure you can work out what changes to make to it do what you want now.

Comment: Yes i tried to change the code by remove "[" and make `var b = a.split(']');` but this not working good cause there is "]" remain with the "Text3"

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way would be to use a regular expression to parse out your text strings, like this:

```
var text = a.match(/\[(.*)\]{1}\[(.*)\]{1}\[(.*)\]{1}/);
```

And then insert each text string `text[1]`, `text[2]`, `text[3]` wherever you want to put it.

So in your example:

```
var b = a.match(/\[(.*)\]{1}\[(.*)\]{1}\[(.*)\]{1}/);
$(this).html("<span>" + b[1] + "</span><span>" + b[2] + "</span><span>" + b[3] + "</span>");
```

Note: The first element in the regex match will be the original string.

Comment: There's something wrong this give error with me i use `a.match(/[^[\]]+(?=])/g);` and works fine, thank you for your answer